# Creating a menu like on Ebay.com

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create menu like on [ebay.com](http://www.ebay.com/) . After taking help from various tutorials I have managed to develop a code for it. You can check it live here: http://cssdesk.com/8sBu5

But the problems with code are:

```
1. The dropdown menu does not look like the menu on ebay.com 

2. The dropdown only works for the very first parent menu (Fashion) because of 
   this code may be:

      .ulclass li:first-of-type:hover .ulsubmenu { 
            display:block;
        } 

3. I want to display only five items per column in the dropdown, but its showing 
   all items in one column
```

I guess I have to use jquery to solve the problem number 2, but I don't understand how to do it.

Could you please help me solve the above problems.

Here's my complete code:

HTML:

```html
<ul class="ulclass">
  <li><a href="#">Fashion</a>

    <ul class="ulsubmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Men's</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Women's</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Books & Magazines</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cameras & Optics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cars & Bikes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Charity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clothing & Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>

 <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>

    <ul class="ulsubmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cellphones</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Books & Magazines</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cameras & Optics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cars & Bikes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Charity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clothing & Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>

 <li><a href="#">Home & Garden</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Women's Clothing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Jwelary & Watches</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Daily Deals</a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.ulclass
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 16px #E7E7E7 inset;
    list-style: none outside none;   
    overflow: auto;


}

.ulclass li a
{
    color: #6A6A6A;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 0 17px;
}

.ulclass li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.ulclass li:first-of-type:hover .ulsubmenu
{
    display:block;
}

.ulsubmenu
{ 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}


.ulsubmenu
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px #EAEAEA;
    display: none;
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 668px;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
.ulsubmenu li
{
    border: medium none;
    width: 222px;
}
.ulsubmenu li:last-of-type
{
    border: medium none !important;
}
.ulsubmenu li a
{
    font-family: arial !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Super easy fix, just remove `:first-of-type` in

```css
.ulclass li:first-of-type:hover .ulsubmenu
{
    display:block;
}
```

Obviously you'll need to add the rest of the submenus before those will work.

Working copy [here](http://cssdesk.com/V4nCt)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please tell me how to make the dropdown show up in the same level of its parent category, just like on ebay. And is it possible to show five items per column in the dropdown using css? Thanks